# Show Selected data using multiple foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

this is dyanmic code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $option = $_POST['option']; 
        $suboption = $_POST['suboption'];
        foreach($option as $opt){
            foreach($suboption as $sub){
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($opt);
                echo "<br>";
                print_r($sub);  
                echo "</pre>";
            }   
        }
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 1"> Option 1<br>
<select name="suboption[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select>
<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 2"> Option 2<br>

<select name="suboption[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 3"> Option 3<br>

<select name="suboption[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Now if i select multi option with multiple suboption then show**

> i select option 1 with suboption 1 or 2 and option 2 with suboption 2 or 3

**Output is**

```
Option 1
Suboption 1
Option 1
Suboption 2
Option 1
Suboption 2
Option 1
Suboption 3
Option 2
Suboption 1
Option 2
Suboption 2
Option 2
Suboption 2
Option 2
Suboption 3
```

**But i Want to**

```
Option 1
Suboption 1 
Option 1
Suboption 2
Option 2
Suboption 2
Option 2
Suboption 3
```

**If i'm select any one option with multiple Suboption then output is right**

> example
>
> i select option 1 with suboption 1 or 2

Output is

```
Option 1
Suboption 1 
Option 1
Suboption 2
```

Please fix this problem

Comment: There are no links between `option` and `suboption`, make way to link them

Answer (score 0):

When you post the data without checking Option 1 checkbox and any sub-option is selected it'll post that data. So you need to use jQuery to enable or disable specific select box, otherwise it'll post data what is not required even.

Also using nested loop will not solve this problem until you have validation on front end.

Comment: Solution is not related to what OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

Relate each suboption with option by using its value in suboption. Also instead of suboption[] you can use unique name for each suboption[], but you need to change you php accordingly.

In HTML change

```
<select name="suboption[]" multiple="multiple">
```

to

```
<select name="suboption[Option 3][]" multiple="multiple">
```

And in Php use the following

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $option = $_POST['option']; 
    $suboption = $_POST['suboption'];

    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($option as $opt){

        foreach($suboption[$opt] as $sub ){
            echo '<br/>';
            print_r($opt);
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($sub);  
        }   
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Complete Code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $option = $_POST['option']; 
        $suboption = $_POST['suboption'];

        echo "<pre>";
        foreach($option as $opt){

            foreach($suboption[$opt] as $sub ){
                echo '<br/>';
                print_r($opt);


                    echo "<br>";
                    print_r($sub);  


            }   
        }
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 1"> Option 1<br>
<select name="suboption[Option 1][]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select>
<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 2"> Option 2<br>

<select name="suboption[Option 2][]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="Option 3"> Option 3<br>

<select name="suboption[Option 3][]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Suboption 1">Suboption 1</option>
  <option value="Suboption 2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option value="Suboption 3">Suboption 3</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry dear its not work for me i have error Undefined index: Option 1  , if i remove [$opt] then program work

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. I thought you will check each checkbox before selecting option. i will correct the answer if you can provide your expected output when checkbox are not selected.

Comment: dear if possible run this code . then you know understood my problem .

Comment: @sanjayjoon Corrected code, hope that is what you are looking for.